# Using inline to get group size in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary, gt

in `gtsummary` I would like to use the `inline_text` to get the number of observations in a category. For example, I would like to get the number and percentage of patients (N = 98) taking Drug A in the following table. Dataframe `trial` with the package `gtsummary`.

```
library(gtsummary)
tab1 <- trial %>% 
     select(trt, marker, stage) %>% 
     tbl_summary(by = trt) %>% 
     add_overall()
```

This results in this table:

[image]

I know that you get values for the whole group using `column = "stat_0"`. For example:

`r inline_text(tab1, variable = stage, level = "T1", column = "stat_0")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the total N with `inline_text()` using the `pattern=` argument.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(marker, grade, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)

inline_text(tbl, variable = "marker", column = "stat_1", pattern = "{N_obs}")
#> [1] "98"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @user:8711276 Thank you Daniel. Would you kindly tell me how to add a correct percentage of the total as well. I tried `{p_nonmiss}` in `pattern` but it's delivering a percent out of the subgroup.

Comment: I don't think you can with `inline_text()`, but you can access all these stats with `tbl$df_by`