# gtsummary::inline_text for `stat_0` with `pattern=`

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to use `gtsummary::inline_text` to get the overall percentage with numerator and denominator, i.e., using `stat_0` with `pattern=`. I am able to get this to work for `stat_1` but get an error for `stat_0`. Thank you for your help!

I found a related post however for a subgroup, i.e., `stat_1`: [Using inline to get group size in gtsummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265212/using-inline-to-get-group-size-in-gtsummary)

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
library(dplyr)

tbl_overall_ex <-
  trial %>%
  filter(!is.na(response)) %>%
  select(trt, response) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_overall()

# Works for  `stat_1`: "29% (28/95)"
inline_text(
  tbl_overall_ex,
  variable = response,
  column = stat_1,
  pattern = "{p}% ({n}/{N})"
)
#> [1] "29% (28/95)"

# Does not work for `stat_0`, should be: 32% (61/193)
inline_text(
  tbl_overall_ex,
  variable = response,
  column = stat_0,
  pattern = "{p}% ({n}/{N})"
)
#> Error: When both `column=` and `pattern=` are specified, the column must be one of 'stat_1', 'stat_2'
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It's currently not possible to use the pattern arg with the `stat_0` column after an `add_overall()`. Post a feature request on the gtsummary page, and we can get it added. It should be there.

Comment: FYI, this feature will be implemented in this pull request. You can subscribe to its updates to follow the progress.
https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/pull/951

Comment: Thank you so much! You are such a kind and helpful package creator/maintainer - I hadn't even posted the issue yet!